# I am trying to replace the values in a dictionary with an updated one and i am not getting the exact result

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-for-loop

So i updated the values of a dictionary into percentage by multiplying by 100. Now i want to replace the initial decimal with the updated results, but instead, i am getting each value  replaced by the whole new values.

```
job_role_overtime_att_rate = {'Healthcare Representative Overtime Rate' : 2/37, ' Human Resources Overtime Rate': 5/13,
      'Laboratory Technician Total' : 31/62, 'Manager Total': 4/27, 'Manufacturing Director Total': 4/39,
      'Research Director Total' : 1/23, 'Research Scientist Total' : 33/97,
      'Sales Executive Total' : 31/94, 'Sales Representative Total' : 16/24}
job_role_overtime_att_rate()
```

```
{'Healthcare Representative Overtime Rate': 0.05405405405405406,
 ' Human Resources Overtime Rate': 0.38461538461538464,
 'Laboratory Technician Total': 0.5,
 'Manager Total': 0.14814814814814814,
 'Manufacturing Director Total': 0.10256410256410256,
 'Research Director Total': 0.043478260869565216,
 'Research Scientist Total': 0.3402061855670103,
 'Sales Executive Total': 0.32978723404255317,
 'Sales Representative Total': 0.6666666666666666}
```

this the result of the above code.

```
for i in job_role_overtime_att_rate.values():
    a = i * 100
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(a))
```

this multiplies the initial result by 100. now

```
5.41
38.46
50.00
14.81
10.26
4.35
34.02
32.98
66.67
```

here is the result.

```
for i in job_role_overtime_att_rate.values():
    a = i * 100
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(a))
    for values in job_role_overtime_att_rate.values():
        values = a
        print(values)
```

this is to replace the intial values with the new one. at least that's what i thought it will do.

```
5.41
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
5.405405405405405
38.46
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
38.46153846153847
50.00
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
50.0
14.81
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
14.814814814814813
10.26
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
10.256410256410255
4.35
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
4.3478260869565215
34.02
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
34.02061855670103
32.98
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
32.97872340425532
66.67
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
66.66666666666666
```

here is what it's returning. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `values = a` simply assigns a new value to the variable `values`; the previous value it had is not relevant, and is not affected in any way (other than the possibility that this was the last reference to it, making it now eligible for garbage-collection).

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the `dict.items()` function to loop through the key and the value.

```
job_role_overtime_att_rate = {
  'Healthcare Representative Overtime Rate': 0.05405405405405406,
  'Human Resources Overtime Rate': 0.38461538461538464,
  'Laboratory Technician Total': 0.5,
  'Manager Total': 0.14814814814814814,
  'Manufacturing Director Total': 0.10256410256410256,
  'Research Director Total': 0.043478260869565216,
  'Research Scientist Total': 0.3402061855670103,
  'Sales Executive Total': 0.32978723404255317,
  'Sales Representative Total': 0.6666666666666666
}

for name, value in job_role_overtime_att_rate.items():
  a = round(value*100, 2)
  job_role_overtime_att_rate[name] = a

print(job_role_overtime_att_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your point is, but you loop over values and in the inner loop again over values.
So for each value you loop over all values, thus it's expected that you will get **n^2** prints for dictionary with **n** values.

If I guess right this code does what you need:

```
for key, value in job_role_overtime_att_rate.items():
    job_role_overtime_att_rate[key]= value*100
```